# Access same firebase user from front and backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to understand how to continue a user session started client side in my backend server.

I'm using `NextJS` for my client app and go `Gin` for backend api calls.

I have some client code that allows a user to login using firebase auth:

```js
import { getAuth, signInWithRedirect, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'

export default function Login() {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  const auth = getAuth()

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)}>Sign In With Google</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is great and works with very little work on my part. Once a user clicks the button, and follows the login instructions, my client app understands who they are using the firebase libraries.

Now I want to make a request to my go gin backend as this current user. How can I continue the session in my backend code as the user who is logged in to my client app? Ideally I would be able to:

1. Log in the client app as `user123`.
2. Make a request to my backend.
3. My backend understands that the request came from my client as `user123`.
4. My backend makes some request to other firebase services as `user123` like creating or updating a Firestore document.

I'm not sure how to go about doing #3. This seems like a common thing and I'm actively looking into what I need to do. I'll answer my own question if I can, but any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to pass the user's ID token from your client to the server, which can then [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and based on that determine whether the user is authorized.

But there's no way to then impersonate that user from your server in calls to Firebase. So you'll have to do the authorization checks for that yourself.

Comment: IIUC, the only way to communicate with something like firestore on my backend is by using the admin sdk?

I was hoping there would be a way to have firestore security rules authorize read/write requests as if the user was making them. Is that only possible from my front end where the user is natively logged in?

Comment: If this is a JavaScript/Node environment, you *can* use the regular Node.js SDK, which is really just the client-side JavaScript SDK, but then as used on non-trusted devices (e.g. IoT).\

Comment: This would be from my server backend written in Go. I think my real question is this: Are firestore/realtime-database/storage [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security#authorization) only applied to requests that come from client libraries?
  
  
The doc you [linked](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) specifically tries to encourage me to use security rules first. From my Go backend I'll have to verify the ID token and perform custom authorization outside of security rules.

Comment: "Are firestore/realtime-database/storage security rules only applied to requests that come from client libraries?" Not exactly, as they're also applied to the REST API when you access that with a Firebase ID token. But indeed, security rules are not applied to requests from trusted environments when using an Admin SDK, as that SDK itself runs with full elevated trust.